# Magento custom theme, overwrite block content

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, theme, design

I developed a custom theme for Magento 1 for one of my projects.
Or tried to follow the guidelines of the communites. I have not overwritten the files `{layout}.xml` I have created new ones on a module and modified the concerned designs. I also created some Block classes that extended the originals but modified some small logic.

I have a doubt though. In these pages all, for convenience, I overwritten the block: "content" entirely, because the structure was always totally different:

```
<block type="core/template" name="content" template="myfront/page/catalog/category/content.phtml">
...
```

Not using `<reference name = "content">` and the various methods inside to customize.

Is this wrong / discouraged? or can I be calm? :)

Answer (score 0):

In the native layout `page.xml`, the block `content` is defined as a `core/text_list` block :

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
```

It seems that you have overrided it with a `core/template` block :

```
<block type="core/template" name="content" template="myfront/page/catalog/category/content.phtml">
```

This could be the cause of a lot of issues as a `core/template` block and a `core/text_list` block don't have the same behavior.

For example, every childs of a `core/text_list` block will be rendered without having to write `echo $this->getChildHtml('your-child')` in the associated template (you can have a look to `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php:35` in order to understand why).

Comment: This is clear, it is calculated, it is not a problem in this case.
I wanted to know if there were any best practices that advised against this.